# fetch cart details from MongoDB Database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, fetch, cart

This is my cart in mongoDB database.
The products is a array of objects. 
 And i want to display some details on cart paage, so i need to fetch these objects from cart model

[image]

This is my code to fetch details:

```
const userID = req.params.id;
const cart = await CartModel.findOne({ UserDetailsId: userID });
console.log("cart", cart);
console.log("products", cart.products);
```

This is my cart in console:

```
[{
totalPrice: 56,
_id: 5f06dd0f0a8ea713f8dc52d2,
products: [ [Object] ],
UserDetailsId: 5f041ef409a05e0a58887009,
__v: 0
```

}]

also my products is:

```
products undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongo returns array of carts. You may see it in console.

```
[{}]
```

That's why you can't access to `cart.products`. Maybe it's better to use `.findOne()` if user may have only one cart.

Comment: What exactly did you try?
Did you try to access products using array (`cart[0].products`)?